# ava.lang.NullPointerException: null at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResources(WebappClassLoader.java:1368) ~[na:na]

Tags: java, web-services, maven, tomcat

I am getting this error in one of my web app. After restarting the tomcat server everything went perfect.Can anybody help to identify the root cause of the issue.

```
2016-07-01 09:29:13,529 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-42] c.a.w.c.s.Caller [Caller.java:88] Couldn't get request Handler
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResources(WebappClassLoader.java:1368) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1040) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.jdk.JDK12Hooks.getResources(JDK12Hooks.java:150) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.DiscoverResources$1.getNextResources(DiscoverResources.java:153) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.DiscoverResources$1.getNextResource(DiscoverResources.java:129) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.DiscoverResources$1.hasNext(DiscoverResources.java:116) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.DiscoverNamesInFile$1.getNextClassNames(DiscoverNamesInFile.java:186) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.DiscoverNamesInFile$1.getNextClassName(DiscoverNamesInFile.java:170) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.DiscoverNamesInFile$1.hasNext(DiscoverNamesInFile.java:157) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.NameDiscoverers$1.getNextIterator(NameDiscoverers.java:143) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.NameDiscoverers$1.hasNext(NameDiscoverers.java:126) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.classes.ResourceClassDiscoverImpl$1.getNextResource(ResourceClassDiscoverImpl.java:159) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.classes.ResourceClassDiscoverImpl$1.hasNext(ResourceClassDiscoverImpl.java:147) ~[commons-discovery-0.2.jar:0.2]
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder$1.run(EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:120) ~[axis-1.2.1.jar:na]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.newFactory(EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:113) ~[axis-1.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.newFactory(EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:160) ~[axis-1.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getEngineConfiguration(Service.java:812) ~[axis-1.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:103) ~[axis-1.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:112) ~[axis-1.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.amadeus.winaproach.connector.soap.Caller.<init>(Caller.java:81) ~[winaproach_connector-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at com.amadeus.qlm.rndrequest.handler.WinaproachRequestHandler.<init>(WinaproachRequestHandler.java:73) [WinaproachRequestHandler.class:na]
    at com.amadeus.qlm.rndrequest.Request.handlRequest(Request.java:128) [Request.class:na]
    at com.amadeus.qlm.rndrequest.SupportRequestCreatorServlet.doPost(SupportRequestCreatorServlet.java:57) [SupportRequestCreatorServlet.class:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646) [tomcat-servlet-api-3.0.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [tomcat-servlet-api-3.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.amadeus.qlm.rndrequest.auth.OAuth2Filter.doFilter(OAuth2Filter.java:77) [OAuth2Filter.class:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237) [spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) [spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_45]
```

Comment: can you put your code please?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I've once seen this error occur when included commons-discovery.jar in `Tomcat/lib` folder.

If you are using `commons-discovery.jar`   put it in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your project and not the Tomcat/lib folder of your project and that should resolve your issue.

Comment: Commons-discovery.jar is in WEB-INF/lib folder only.Can there be any other issue.Please help.

Comment: I would suggest to check your classpath for the jar's you are using and if they exist in Tomcat/lib too, move them to WEB-INF/lib. There must be some dublicated jar there...